# css problems with nav and h1

Tags: html, css

i made a second nav but it keeps moving the H1 on the page
the text in the h1 needs to stay in the center but it keeps movig tried some things didnt work
i used this css

```
.nav2 {
position: relative;
float: left;
top:190px;
left:24px;
}
.nav2 a {
position: relative;
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #777777;
border: 1px solid black;
border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
top: 5px;
left: 2px;
padding-top: 9px;
padding-bottom: 9px;
padding-left: 49px;
padding-right: 49px;
margin-bottom: 3px;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(37,38,41,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
}
```

the h1 css

```
.home h1, .services h1, .projecten h1 {
position: relative;
top: -75px;
text-align: center;
border: 1px solid black;
border-radius: 3px;
width: 1000px;
padding-top: 4px;
padding-bottom: 4px;
color: #777777;
background-color: black;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(54,54,54,1) 0%,rgba(21,21,21,1)       50%,rgba(16,16,16,1) 51%,rgba(36,36,36,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */

}
```

Comment: Please provide the html as well.

Comment: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: There really should be no need to use `position:relative` as much as you are. Try using margins & padding to position elements properly.

Answer (score -1):

Add `!important` to your `H1`:

```
text-align: center !important;
```

Comment: didnt change anything